# store logo not displayed instead logo alt message is displaying in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

#### store logo not displayed instead logo alt message is displaying in magento

I've Given Like This in config->Design->header
Image :  image/img.jpg
Image Alt : Logo
but in Home page it didn't show logo instead it display Image Alt

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've kept your `img.jpg` in the correct folder

> eg: skin \ frontend \ `packagename` \ `themename` \ images \ img.jpg

Flush your Magento cache also and see if it comes up.

If the prob still exists check if your folder permissions are set right.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Image path

```
 images/img.jpg
```

might be spell mistake, path is "images/img.jpg" not "image/img.jpg"